# Link de editar está desproporcional quando desabilitado

Tags: bug, status-pronto, design

Quando o link de editar está desabilitado, ele fica cinza claro, mas com fonte maior que os outros links ao lado dele:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Seria melhor do mesmo tamanho, não?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isto foi resolvido e vai ao ar com o próximo build.

---

This has been fixed and should go out in the next build.